# Typing 'a' in the search bar in AWS Systems Manager Session Manager console makes everything disappear

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, user-interface, aws-ssm, aws-session-manager

Whenever I type the character `a` in the search bar on the AWS Systems Manager Session Manager console, the whole console goes white and everything gets disappeared. I have to refresh the page to make everything appear again.

URL: https://eu-central-1.console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/session-manager/sessions?region=eu-central-1

I think it is a bug and needs to be fixed or am I the only one who experiences this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct.  I also get the same behavior, and when it happens I see this error in the web console (Chrome Developer Tools):

[image]

So that seems to confirm that there is a code problem at least at this moment.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I have posted this in AWS re:Post and AWS is looking into this.

Comment: Answer by AWS can be found here: https://repost.aws/questions/QU4yOr6jpKRAKm0yIyw_mKig/typing-a-in-the-search-bar-in-aws-systems-manager-session-manager-console-makes-everything-disappear
They agreed with the issue.